# How can I represent a binary tree in python?

Tags: python, data-structures

Currently I'm representing a binary tree in the following manner:

```
[None,2,[None,3,None]]
```

The tree above is rooted at 2. `None` means that the branch is empty.

I'd rather implement this in a list.
Are there better ways to do this (without resorting to creating classes) ?

Comment: Why the aribtrary limitation "without resorting to creating classes"?  I think the best way to do this *is* to define a class.

Comment: "Better ways" in which respect? More efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to represent a binary tree using a flat list, as described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Arrays). How wasteful this method is would depend on the shape of your tree.

I am curious as to why you insist on avoiding classes. If you were to wrap this in a class, you could define a clean API and hide the details of your implementation from the eventual user.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to represent a complete binary tree (i.e. with all nodes having two children, except the leaves), then you can use just a flat list the represent the tree.

You can easily determine the father and two children of a node like this:

```
def leftChild(lst,i):
  try: 
    return lst[i*2]
  except IndexError:
    return None

def rightChild(lst,i):
  try: 
    return lst[i*2+1]
  except IndexError:
    return None

def father(lst,i):
  try:
    return lst[i/2]
  except IndexError:
    return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way:
an array of arrays, where item with index 0 is a root item:

```
[['Level A', 'A1', 'A2'], ['Level B', 'B1', 'B2'], ['Level C', 'C1', 'C2']]
```

Classes can make a simple application unnecessarily complex, especially if you deal with simple trees like represented above.